# React useState hook wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am in a situation where I need to add additional data to the state object whenever a particular attribute changes. I'm using `useState` hook to set the state object and passing it to components downstream. This is a working piece of code:

```
interface FilterType {
  timeframe: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}

function ParentComp() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<FilterType>({});
  return <ChildComp filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters}>;
}

function ChildComp({
  setFilters: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<FilterType>>,
  filters: FilterType,
}) {
  // onChange sets `timeframe` in filters
  return <DropDown onChange={setFilters} value={filters.timeframe} > 
}
```

What I need to happen now is whenever `timeframe` changes in the `filters` object I need to set `startDate` and `endDate` in the same object because this is doing an API request to the backend with `react-query`. Now, I can use a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
function ParentComp() {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const startDate, endDate = getDatesFromTimeframe(filters.timeframe);
    setFilters((prevFilters) => {...prevFilters, startDate, endDate});
  }, [filters.timeframe])
```

The problem with this `useEffect` is that it will make 2 requests to the backend, once when `DropDown` sets `timeframe` and a second time when this `useEffect` is setting `startDate` and `endDate`.

So I was thinking, there has to be a way to wrap the `setFilters` with my own function and pass that wrapper to the `Dropdown`, something like:

```
function ParentComp() {
  ...
  const setFilterWrapper() {
    const filterCopy = deepCopy(filters);
    const startDate, endDate = getDatesFromTimeframe(filters.timeframe);
    setFilters(() => {...filterCopy, startDate, endDate});
  }

  return <DropDown onChange={setFilterWrapper} value={filters.timeframe} >
```

I'm not understanding how to make `setFilterWrapper` behave like a `React.SetStateAction` or if I have a concept wrong here and I should be doing something else.

Comment: Your wrapper doesn't accept any arguments, is this correct?

Comment: @BrianThompson no, my wrapper doesn't work that's what I'm trying to figure, what it should take and if it should return anything to be passed down as SetState.